# Attempting to figure out the number of duplicate strings in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, return

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Nie.png)

I've researched on how to find how many duplicates of strings are in a string array. I think I have done this correctly but the method I'm using requires me to return a string value, but it will not let me return the value. In short, I am trying to find the food that most patients w/ "food poisoning" have eaten recently. The "common food" needs to be the value in the array when it's been repeated 5 times. Any suggestions?

Comment: Study about the scope of local variables.

Comment: Add your code here, not screenshot

Comment: What do you mean by value ? Are you trying to find how many times "common food" is eaten and want to return the value of this count ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strems` to find the most common element in array

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] data = {"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"};

        Map.Entry<String, Long> entry = Stream.of(data)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .orElse(null);

        if (entry != null) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these situation you can use maps for both optimization and usability.

Below is your method. I did not write all data.

I have created a foodMap.

```
static String mostCommonFood() {
    String data[] = {"a","b"};
    Map<String, Integer> foodMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (String val : data) {
        if (foodMap.containsKey(val)) {
            foodMap.put(val, foodMap.get(val)+1);
        } else {
            foodMap.put(val, 1);
        }
    }
    String mostCommonFood = "";
    int mostCommonFoodValue = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> foods : foodMap.entrySet()) {
        if(foods.getValue() > mostCommonFoodValue) {
            mostCommonFoodValue = foods.getValue();
            mostCommonFood = foods.getKey();
        }
    }
    return mostCommonFood;
}
```